# TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable without transforming entire object to str

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I am attempting to fetch user data from a postgres database and I am able to do so successfully however when it comes to serlialization, am receiving the following:

```
TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

Here is my code:

execute query function:

```
def execute_query(self, query: str, to_dict: bool = False) -> psycopg2.extensions.cursor:
        if to_dict:
            self._cur = self._con.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
        else:
            self._cur = self._con.cursor()

        self._cur.execute(query)
        self._con.commit()

        return self._cur
```

caller:

```
def add_user():
    db = DatabaseConnector()
    db.connect()

    # add new user
    db.execute_query(f"INSERT INTO user (uname, email, fname, lname, passwordhash, create_date) VALUES ('usera', 'usera@gmail.com', 'Jesse', 'Pinkman', 'myhash', 'NOW()');")

    # fetch new user
    try:
        user = db.execute_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname = 'usera'", to_dict=True)
        fetch = user.fetchone()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        db.close()

    print(json.dumps(fetch)) # <---- exception raised
```

According to other related stack overflow posts, I could do the following to transform datetime objects to strings, however the entire list object comes back as a string and not the individual datetime object being converted to a string.

```
class DateEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, date):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


user = json.dumps(fetch, cls=DateEncoder)
```

I have also tried using the following:

```
json.dumps(user, default=str)
```

However returns the result of `str` rather than a `dict`

My working suggestion is the following where I pull out the date and convert it to a string, however is there a better way to do this?

```
sample = {'uname': fetch['uname'], 'email': fetch['email'], 'fname': fetch['fname'], 'lname`': fetch['lname'], 'create_date': str(fetch['create_date'])}
```

Comment: The entire purpose of `json.dumps` is to convert objects to a string format; what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: @snakecharmerb maybe i read wrong by the suggested solutions, but i though that any datetime object would be converted to a string all while maintaining the integrity of the object it resides in.

Comment: Given a list or dict, `json.dumps` will serialise the object and all the objects it contains, if possible.  For example, `json.dumps([{'foo': 'bar'}, {'baz': 'quux'}])` -> '[{"foo": "bar"}, {"baz": "quux"}]'.